# Substring in SQL to remove characters from column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for some assistance to `substring` key characters from column.

The column values look like this `_175776_1`. The length can be of any value, so a `substring` at fixed position elements will not cater for this. I am looking to remove the first underline (`_`) and select the contents before the next underline (`_`).

So the result on the above example would be `175776`.

Comment: I think you should use CHARINDEX

Comment: CHARINDEX will not work as the value i.e. 175776 could be either 4 char, 5 char or 6 char etc. So the position will always change. Basically all i need is everything between the UNDERSCORE characters effectively.

Comment: You were correct, found the solution to solve this, Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select left(v1.str, charindex('_', v1.str) - 1)
from (values ('_175776_1')) v(str) cross apply
     (values (stuff(str, 1, 1, ''))) v1(str);
```

Comment: Not really, i have added an example of where i need this to function.

    declare String nvarchar(40)
set String='_175776_1'
select String, 
left(String, charindex('_', String) - 1) as ex
 from  [test].[Schema].[Table]
;

Comment: the Set String should = _175776_1

Comment: Result should = 175776

Comment: @jasonbarry . . . You can run this code . That is what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `charindex` with `cross apply`.

```
with your_table as (select '_175776_1' as txt1)

select txt1, txt2
from your_table t1
cross apply (select charindex( '_', txt1) as i1) t2
cross apply (select charindex( '_', txt1, (i1 + 1)) as i2 ) t3
cross apply (select substring( txt1,(i1+1), (i2-i1-1)) as txt2) t4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to display your desired result.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('_175776_1',PATINDEX('%_%','_175776_1')+1,PATINDEX('%_','_175776_1')-3)
```